# Can someone help me please?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

$A^+A=I$ where $A^{+}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, $A_{m \times n}$

I have tried with $(A^TA)^{-1}=A^{-1}{A^T}^{-1}$ but the matrix is not squared

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you trying to show that $A^+ A = I$? If so, just move parentheses around and see what you get. Also, please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Yes I want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice

$A^{+}A=((A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T})A=(A^{T}A)^{-1}(A^{T}A)$